# Possible to add an array to a dataSource variable? c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource

My goal is to use two seperate arrays, a string array and an int array, in a dataGridView.DataSrouce but I don't know how, or if it's even possible to do this.

```
// this is what i have now
dataGridView.DataSource = playerName.Select(x =>
            new { PlayerName = x }).ToList();

//this is what im looking to do, if it makes any sense
dataGridView.DataSource = playerName.Select(k =>
            new { PlayerName = k, plrRoll = playerRoll.Select(x => 
                new { roll = x }) }).ToList();
```

currently it just prints empty rows in the plrRoll column

Is it possible to have a user generated roll and a user generated name put together and displayed in a dataGridView?

Comment: `dataGridView` can display `tabular data` not `hierarchical data`

Comment: is there another way for me to go about doing this?

Comment: As I said, you may have to convert `hierarchical data` to `tabular data` and accept the thing that *There may be some duplicated values in some columns*. Another choice is use some custom `DataGridView` which supports displaying `parent-child relationship data`. You can also use 2 `DataGridViews`, 1 for `parent` and 1 for `child`.

Comment: Yea, I'm currently using 2 separate dataGridViews at the moment but the goal i wanted to accomplish in the end was being able to organize the data, rolls, and the names so that they would appear together from high to low value.